# github push access denied to someone

Tags: github

I'm trying to push several files into my own repository on GitHub but my access was denied. Here's the message:

```
remote: Permission to lily0225/TravellingSalesmanProblem.git denied to ls3311.

fatal: unable to access
'https://github.com/lily0225/TravellingSalesmanProblem.git/': 
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

`ls3311` is a friend whom I worked with on a previous project but we ended up not using GitHub.
I don't understand why my access was denied to her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Github seems only supports ssh way to read&write the repo, although https way also displayed 'Read&Write'.

No: the write aspect is only dependent on your GitHub right: owner of or collaborator on a GitHub project.
And that for https or ssh.

See "[Permission levels for a user account repository](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/)".

So make sure your own GitHub account [has been declared collaborator on your friend's repo](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/).

---

```
remote: Permission to lily0225/TravellingSalesmanProblem.git denied to ls3311.
```

That means you are pushing to your own repo `lily0225` with `ls3311`'s credentials.

That happens when a credential helper has cached `ls3311`'s credentials in association with `lily0225/TravellingSalesmanProblem.git`.
Check for a credential helper on your Git config:

```
git config -l | grep credential
```

On Windows, for instance, open your [Windows Credential Manager](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/credential-manager-where-windows-stores-passwords-other-login-details) and look for a `github.com` entry.

Comment: Thanks Vonc. But could you explain a little more why my access is denied to her? I hesitate adding her as a collaborator because she is not a collaborator for the project that I want to push. And what if in the future, I want to push other projects that she is not a collaborator of?

Comment: @lily0225 Sure, I have edited my answer. Are you on Windows? What git version are you using?

Comment: I'm using terminal on a macbook pro

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem and figured out what's cause.

Github seems only supports ssh way to read&write the repo, although https way also displayed 'Read&Write'.

So you need to change your repo config on your PC to ssh way:

edit `.git/config` file under your repo directory
find `url`=entry under section `[remote "origin"]`
change it from `url=https://mirzaobaid@github.com/pakistan/lunch_call.git to url=ssh://git@github.com/pakistan/lunch_call.git.` that is, change all the texts before @ symbol to `ssh://git`
Save config file and quit. now you could use git push origin master to sync your repo on GitHub